How to get current finder window in AppleScript
I have written the script below to add a README file to the current folder (if there isn't already one). While researching how to do this, I came across two ways of getting the path of the current Finder location:

target of front window
insertion location

What is the use case for each? Is target of front window more appropriate in my script? I tried both options but there didn't seem to be any differences, not even when a folder at the current Finder location was selected.
tell application "Finder"
    set currentFolder to target of front window as string
    set readmePath to currentFolder & "README.md"
    
    if not (exists file readmePath) then
        do shell script "touch " & quoted form of POSIX path of readmePath
        reveal file readmePath
    else
        display dialog "README.md already exists in this folder."
    end if
end tell


Each Finder window possesses its own target property. To use the command, you must specify the window in some manner as it can be applied to any open window. Of course, if no windows are open then its use will generate an error.
You can both get and set the target of a window. The latter means that you can change the target.
tell application "Finder" to set winTarg to target of Finder window 1

            –or–

tell application "Finder" to set target of Finder window 1 to (path to movies folder)

Because of this flexibility, you have to ensure that you are working with the desired window. If something changes the order of the windows while the script is running, depending upon how the script is written, it may change the results.
insertion location is a property of the Finder application and while it changes depending upon what window —if any— is frontmost, there is only ever one. It aligns with the location that a new folder would be created if you chose that command from the Finder's file menu, so it doesn't require an open window. You don't have to specify anything and as it is read-only, it is simple to use.
tell application "Finder" to insertion location

        -or- 

tell application "Finder" to set insLoc to insertion location

Both commands will produce the same result when working with the front window. You can coerce the results of either into the desired format, eg posix path. Given the simplicity of your current script, both should be fine to use.
